# importing zip file in google Colaboratory stored in google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I need to access the data stored on google drive in .zip format into the google collaboratory.
 As to train the model every time I need to upload the data with big size.is there any other efficient way to directly access the data without uploading every time?

Answer (score 3):

A minimal way to extract zip file from google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Open the link in a new tab-> you will get a code - copy that back into the prompt you now have access to google drive check:

```
!unzip "/content/gdrive/My Drive/file_name.zip"
```

Answer (score 2):

First you install and import libraries

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

Then you authenticate yourself and connect to Google Drive

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Then you download the file your_data.zip from Google Drive to Colab.

```
fid = drive.ListFile({'q':"title='your_data.zip'"}).GetList()[0]['id']
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': fid})
f.GetContentFile('your_data.zip')
```

From here you can unzip them and do whatever training you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount google drive to colab instance using `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.

The following code is from this blog post: https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

The code above will show authorization URL and ask for verification code.

After providing the code it should be possible to mount google drive to a local folder:

```py
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```